# как посмотреть сборку в C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

есть программа, которая компилируется в исполняемый файл exe, есть ли методы в C# которые позволяют заглянуть в этот exe?
меня интересуют какие файлы в нем лежат

Comment: Думаю, что в вашем exe-файле лежит только один этот самый exe-файл. Вы имели в виду _зависимые сборки_?

Comment: Вы хотите знать, из каких файлов .cs была скомпилирована сборка? Этой информации там нет. Может вы хотите посмотреть ресурсы в сборке? В общем, уточните.